# Query for Model in CI

Tags: codeigniter

I am designing an application in CI and after several try was able to establish sql query as :

```
select inv2.id,inv1.uniqueid,inv2.pastamount_due, c.name FROM invoices as inv2 join (SELECT max(id) as maxid, uniqueid from invoices GROUP by uniqueid ) as inv1 on (inv2.id =inv1.maxid and inv2.uniqueid = inv1.uniqueid) JOIN client as c ON inv2.uniqueid = c.uniqueid
```

Now trying to convert the same query into Model In CI but I am not sure how to go ahead as this one include nested query with joins. Can someone please help me ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Query Builder](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html) to create and execute the sql statement. But more often than not it is more efficient to simply use `$this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE')`.

```
$sql = "select inv2.id,inv1.uniqueid,inv2.pastamount_due, c.name 
        FROM invoices as inv2 
        JOIN (SELECT max(id) as maxid, uniqueid from invoices GROUP by uniqueid)
        as inv1 on (inv2.id=inv1.maxid and inv2.uniqueid=inv1.uniqueid) 
        JOIN client as c ON inv2.uniqueid = c.uniqueid";

$query = $this->db->query($sql);
if($query !== false)
{
   return $query->result();
}

return NULL; //$query is false. Probably due to bad syntax in the query string
```